# PowerShell: execute command before PS exits

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to execute a simple command (to delete a directory) when PowerShell exits.

So far I have this:

```
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -SourceIdentifier –Action { cmd.exe /c "D:\removedir.bat" }
```

Off course the .bat file works, but not when PS closes. I have tried several things inside the ScriptBlock like: Start-Process, Invoke-Item, etc. to execute the .bat file after PS exits, but I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Why is it important that it triggers on _exit_ (as opposed to "when the script is done with everything else")? Is the script waiting on something?

Comment: I guess it doesn't work because batch file will be run in the same session, which is about to close, so it gets terminated immediately. Can you move the commands from the batch file directly into the `-Action` scriptblock?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: We use a Generic script that will be used by several collegues and it will create a directory to store the parameters per session.

Comment: @zett42: Sorry for not mentioning, I have tried that too  That doesn't work either.

Comment: Wrap the script and cleanup action in `try/finally`: `try{ & GenericScript.ps1 @paramArgs } finally { Perform-Cleanup }`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the conceptual event you want to react to is *not* "PowerShell is exiting", but rather "My code is done executing".

For this, you'll want [a `try`/`finally` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.2#freeing-resources-using-finally):

```
try {
  # Start by placing your existing code in the `try` block as-is
  & GenericScript.ps1 @paramArgs
}
finally {
  # ... and then perform your cleanup tasks once the `try` block is done executing.
  Perform-Cleanup
}
```

The `finally` block will execute *immediately before exiting the `try` block* - in other words, if all the code in the `try` block executed successfully, the `finally` code will execute right after as usual (as if the `try`/`finally` statements weren't there at all) - but if any terminating errors are thrown by the code in the `try` block, the `finally` block will *still* execute before control is returned to the caller - which sounds like exactly the kind of guarantee you're looking for :)